# GCP - how to add a Google account as an IAM principal to a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

Which GCP SDK command to use to add a Google account (email) to a GCP project?

From the UI, it is possible.

[image]

However, [gcloud iam](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam) command nor [gcloud projects](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/) do not have an option.

Comment: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding` what you're looking for?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza, not yet. I am trying to understand why adding a principal/user having a google email account is to be added using "projects" command and why "add-iam-policy-binding". Policy is a definition of which roles to grant to a principal? then why using it to add Google email account principal?

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding) you can see some examples: "To add an IAM policy binding for the role of 'roles/editor' for the user 'test-user@gmail.com' on a project with identifier 'example-project-id-1', run: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding example-project-id-1 --member='user:test-user@gmail.com' --role='roles/editor'`" . So, here you can see how to provide (bind) IAM role to the user on the project level.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza, thank you for the follow up. Appreciated. I think I am missing something. So in GCP, it is possible to bind a role to a user which has not existed yet? In my experience in UNIX, AWS, we need to first create an account or a user to associate any user/group permission, which seems not to be the case with GCP.

Comment: Have you checked [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#structure)? "A principal, also known as a member or identity, which can be a user account, service account, Google group, or domain." So, the principal should exist, but you can use already existed accounts like `someusername@gmail.com` or a `domain.name` if your already use Google Workspace (G Suite).

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza, thanks. I think I misunderstand that some action of account/user creation should happen within GCP/IAM because I am from UNIX/AWS background where useradd or adding a user in IAM is required to have a user principal in the system. I suppose GCP utilizes already created Google email account. If the account does not exist, then an error would occur at gcloud auth login etc. Is it correct?

Comment: You won't be able to gran permissions if the account doesn't exist, you'll get an error message immideatelly like this: `Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account, Google Workspace account, or Cloud Identity account.` Is everything clear now?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza, thanks for the explanation. I think now I understood the idea.

Comment: Thanks! I posted a community wiki answer with a brief summary of comments. Please accept/apvote if it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post this community wiki answer to make the solution provided at the comment section more visible. Feel free to edit or expand.

As it was suggested by *@Joachim Isaksson* at the comment section, you should use the command [`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding):

> Adds a policy binding to the IAM policy of a project, given a project ID and the binding. One binding consists of a member, a role, and an optional condition.
>
> To add an IAM policy binding for the role of 'roles/editor' for the user 'test-user@gmail.com' on a project with identifier 'example-project-id-1', run:
>
> ```
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding example-project-id-1 --member='user:test-user@gmail.com' --role='roles/editor'
> ```

More information you can find at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding).

In addition, please have a look at the document [Understanding policies](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#structure).

> A principal, also known as a member or identity, which can be a user account, service account, Google group, or domain.

So, the principal should exist, but you can use already existed accounts like Google Account or Google Workspace account.